# How to make a div visible via fadeIn() function

Tags: jquery, fadein

I've got a div in display:none, like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">My Text</div>
```

I want my div appears so I used:

```
$("#mydiv").fadeIn();
```

But it does not work... My div stay at display:none...

Thanks for your help.

---

**Works now... It was juste a quote error... Don't Blame Me :)
Thanks for your help guys**

Comment: Did you place this in something like `$(document).ready(function () { $("#mydiv").fadeIn(); });`?

Comment: Yes insertusernamehere.

Comment: Hm, should work: http://jsfiddle.net/kWSCx/ - Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hide the element in jquery with

```
$('#mydiv').hide();
```

than do the fadein and it should work (should also work with display:none)

otherwise show me some code --> http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/7NdPJ/

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the inline "display: none" and use fadeOut() to hide the element first? Also, does anything of note get logged in the JS console?